# Air Bag Module under the drivers seat

Tags: chevrolet, silverado, supplemental-restraint-system

I have a small blue wire that has become disconnected under my drivers seat in my 2006 Chevy Silverado regular cab.  I noticed it when I removed the seat.  Its shorter them the wires that connect to the seat.  Does anyone know where this wire would go.  I looked at the connector to the Air Bag Module and can not see where it would go.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Is the wire coming down from the seat or up from the floor? And is it a single wire or a pair?

Comment: It is coming from the floor and appears to come from the passenger seat.  Its not as long as the blue wire that connects to the frame of the drivers seat.

Comment: What I'm wondering is, if it's for some option for the seat which you don't have. I've got so much crap (read: options) under my the seat of my 06 Silvy, I don't know if I can see anything.

Comment: Thats what i thought when I saw it but the rubber is stripped off the end like it was hooked to a connector.  I noticed on the seat connector that one pin might have had 2 wires going to it so I hooked it up.  Then when I started the truck up the Service Air Bag came on the dash and the air bag light is on

Comment: I think the only thing on the driver's side which has to do with the airbag is the seat belt retractor.

Comment: Can you provide pictures of the wire in question and where you think it goes?

Comment: I also checked that and didnt see where that wire could have went.  I hooked my code reader up to my truck and it doesnt flash any codes.  It is a mystery and the Haynes manual does not have the wiring diagram in it.  I will have to visit Pull A Part and find a wrecked one and look at it.

Comment: Let me get a picture.

Comment: Realize, your code reader has to specifically be able to read SRS codes to pull them from the airbag.

Comment: I added the picture as my profile picture.4

Comment: Is there a weight switch on the seat springs? That wire may have come off that.

Comment: There is another connector but didnt see anywhere the wire could have gone.  That switch has 2 wires going to it.